# Elastic modulus of space-time?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, gravitational-waves

Intuitively, a wave is something that propagates through an elastic medium (except possibly for ocean waves); is it possible to consider space-time as such a medium? And if so, what would its elastic tensor(s) be, if that is the correct term (it has been many years since I learned the elements of physics)?

And by extension, can all waves propagating through a field (such as electro-magnetic waves) be described in this way?

***Edit***

Just to clarify, I do understand that electro-magnetic waves propagate through vacuum, which may or may not be 'nothing', whatever that means. However, any physical theory is a somewhat accurate, but not perfect, model of reality, and considering alternative models is not *a priori* wrong.

Let me rephrase the question above: is it possible to assign some sort of elastic modules to space-time as it relates to gravitational waves, or to vacuum as it relates to electro-magnetic waves? Or perhaps a more fundamental question: If we are given a wave phenomenon, is it possible, mathematically, to derive some sort of elastic properties of whatever 'medium' carries the wave?

Comment: Use the expression for the speed of propagation from the wave equation ...?

Answer (score 1):

sorry. but your intuition that waves always propagate trough an elastic medium is not true. Light waves go through vacuum. in the 18. and part of the 19. century, your intuition was used to describe light, but Michelins experiment, showing, that light moves independently from earth movement through this elastic medium , showed, that it did not exist.

Comment: My question is meant as a 'what if' - I know very well that this isn't mainstream thinking. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: you still have to postulate for vacuum, relativ to what is your elastic medium not moving. if earth is carrying it along, or the sun or the former imagined absolute space?